# How to hide android keyboard on button click using cordova

Tags: cordova

I have used keyboard plugin to hide the keyboard but it's not working.

My code : with `ionic-plugin-keyboard` installed

I used `hidekb()` in `ng-click`

```
$scope.hidekb = function (){
    cordova.plugins.Keyboard.close()
};
```

Comment: In what way is it "not working"? Are you getting a specific error message?

Comment: 'onKeyboardHide is not defined' and unable to add cordova.plugins....

Comment: Keyboard.hide() is also not working.

Comment: Have you verified that hidekb is called ?

Comment: yes,it is used in ng-click..

Answer (score 0):

The first line you wrote :

```
document.addEventListener("hidekeyboard", onKeyboardHide);
```

Will add a listener. When the keyboard will be hidden, the function `onKeyboardHide` (that must be defined) will be called. So it is not what you want to do.

The second line you wrote :

```
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hide();
```

Is quite what you want to do. Except that you must use :

```
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.close();
```

If I guess well the plugins that you used (you didn't mentioned it).

To be able to use this function, you must first add the plugin to your project :

```
cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-keyboard
```

Also, in order to use the plugin, you must wait that the plugin is initiated by waiting the `deviceready` event (but on a button it should be ok).

Comment: i am using both cordova-plugin-keyboard and ionic-plugin-keyboard but unable to hide the keyboard on button click

Comment: You should use only one. Have you tried `cordova.plugins.Keyboard.close();` ?

Comment: You need to add the plugin. And maybe, intellisense doesn't work well

Comment: i have already added the plugin and tried close method it's not working...i need to hide the keyboard on ng-click using angularjs...is there any other way to do it.

Comment: What is the code that you wrote ? Can you please edit your post ?